# Ionic2 focus input without keyboard opening

Tags: android, ionic2, keyboard

We are doing ionic2 application to scan the barcode and take the user to detail of that product. The screen has input field with Opacity 0 since the input should not be visible to user to prevent user interaction. Right now the functionality works fine but the keyboard opens by default when ever user visits this screen.

I tried to user below code to hide the keyboard but this looks odd as the keyboard visible for fraction of time and then hidden;

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
```

I want to focus the input without keyboard open, is it possible ? could you please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After al long research found that there is no solution to focus the input without keyboard. Hence i changed the approach and create the broadcast receiver to handle the barcode scan.

Comment: How would you achieve , can u please share it i have similar issue in my scan app.

Comment: @Husain : the scanner gives the input value in broadcast receiver, from native we can execute the JS method which takes the barcode as input value.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to work with broadcast, it is being helpful if u share any knowledge for the same. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Husain : In my case we have the Barcode Scanner Application, which use to broadcast the scanned number. From our application we have the receiver which will handle the broadcast. Let me know which scanner application are you using

Comment: I had a zebra device which contained In-built Laser scanner , so i never require an scan application.

Comment: Check with Laser scanner document, is there any broadcast been triggered, most probably it wont. Seems that is stand alone application.